# google IAB version 3 and static response test products

Tags: android, in-app-billing

First thanks to Google for the new IAB it is much easier to use and it has a more complete feature set.

However i think i hit a "small" issue when testing it with the [static responses](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static) from Google Play.

Following the guideline and making use of the helper classes in the example implementation it seems that you never get the result back on your activity onActivityResult if you start a purchase with one of the test products.
So after a bit of digging it seems that, at least for those products, it still starts the previous implementation IN_APP_NOTIFY broadcast. Has any of you stumble on this issue?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

got this line in logcat:

D/DfeApi(1367): [1] DfeRequest.deliverResponse: Not delivering second response for request=[[ ] https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/details?doc=inapp:com.mobizy:android.test.purchased NORMAL 103]

EDIT:

ok so it was a blunder. what happened is that there was a codepath that ignored the onActivityResult. So it's fixed and it's working ... Thanks for the replies people.

Comment: Hm.. android.test.purchased works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, that is not my experience. The 'purchased' product seems to work just fine: displays FAKE card and I can buy 'gas' for the sample app. But they don't mention it in the documentation though, so the static responses are probably not really supported.

Comment: but does it invoke the onActivityResult callback?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you didn't clean up your AndroidManifest.xml?  The 2.0 implementation had you register receivers for the various IAB messages.

When I upgraded to 3.0 I had to remove those receivers as its all handled by the IabHelper.